# netbeans profiler: how can I know where the char[] and byte[] usage come from?

Tags: java, jsf, memory-management, netbeans, profiler

I have a webapp (JSF 2) which I develop with Netbeans 7.2, running on Tomcat 7.

With the Netbeans profiler, I see that just after the first page is loaded by the browser (a simple form with two fields!), the memory usage is already fluctuating around 250Mb, with char[], byte[], string and stringBuilder taking around 95% of this memory usage.

How can I know what causes such a high memory use?

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, so I can't go in detail how to figure that, but keep in mind that such a webapp profiler also profiles server's (Tomcat's) internal classes. As to the high usage of `char[]` and `byte[]`; the `char[]` represents more than often the internal characters/char buffers of `String`/`StringBuilder`/etc and the `byte[]` represents more than often the internal byte buffers of `InputStream`/`OutputStream`/etc. All those chars/bytes have ultimately to be stored *somewhere*, right? The most sane data structures are then `char[]` and `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the profiler in memory profiling mode you can select recording the allocation traces. That way you can track down who creates these data.

When you want to see who is referencing the data preventing it being garbage collected you can take a heap dump (right during the profiling session) and analyse it in the profiler's integrated heap walker.

Actually, in your case I would start with the heap dump to see which higher level structures keep most of those char[] and byte[] arrays and then look at the memory profiling snapshot and try to find where in the code they are instantiated.